# numerical analysis and weakness of calculator

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, calculator

Suppose that our calculator can calculate $e^x$ so well.But its program for calculating $\ln (x)$ is poor.
How to improve the accuracy of $ln(x)$ by using the fact that
 $$ln(a)=b+ln(1+\frac{a-e^b}{e^b})$$ and the Taylor's inequality??

Comment: What do you mean by "weak", "poor" etc in this context? The number of accurate digits?

Comment: I guess the idea is that $b+(a-e^{b})/e^{b}$ is a better approximation to $\ln(a)$ than $b \approx \ln(a)$ which the calculator has outputted. (can you prove that?)

Comment: it means that it can not calculate this more than a specific decimal place

Comment: This is simply one step of the Newton iteration to solve $e^b=a$. Note that  -contrary to your assumption-  in most cases $\ln$ can be computed with more accuracy than $\exp.$